# PhpMyAdmin: MySql Field in one table refer to field in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have created a database with two tables user and userdiary.

In the "user" table I have id and email fields. 
In the "userdiary" table I have a field called email. I want to link this field with the one in the "user" table.

I'm using phpmyAdmin to add sql statements. 
I tried doing `ALTER TABLE userdiary FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES user(email)`

but I get the error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES user(email)' at line 1

I looked at many forums but could not find a solution to this issue. 
It will be great if any of you could help me resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the keyword `add`:

```
ALTER TABLE userdiary ADD FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES user(email)
----------------------^
```

Comment: I'm getting the error #1005 - Can't create table 'mypersonaldiary.#sql-aa0_36'